# how to try two possible web-service directions

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I've been working calling a web service but this service sometimes is working in one direction and sometimes in other direction. i want to call the service and if the service is down in this direction i want to try the other direction. I've been working with the php function is_soap_fault() but when the first direction fails i use is_soap_fault() and the other direction (working direction) never give the result.

```
$service="http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/blabla/webservices.nsf/getDetails?WSDL"; 
try{
    $client = new SoapClient($service);
    $result = $client->getDetailPoints();
}catch (SoapFault $e){
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _direction_? It's not a term I recognize.

Comment: $service="http://xxx.xx.x.xxx/blabla/webservices.nsf/getDetails?WSDL";  and   $service="http://yyy.yy.y.yyy/blabla/webservices.nsf/getDetails?WSDL"; Frits van Campen